# extract data on turtle when getting into a specific area

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem exporting data from my turtles and I was hoping someone could help me. 
I have 9 turtles called "renards" with two variables "stress" and "poids" that change as the move along. I would like to get the results of these variables once the turtles get into a specific area of the world (they cross a line that's between the patch xcor -24 and ycor 39 and the patch xcor 52 ycor 82) and once they cross this imaginary line the variable are sent to an excel file (or other types of file if more convenient)to have a table with each renard numbered and the value for each variable in a column.

I hope my explanations are clear enough and that there is a solution to my problem. Here is how I created my turtles:

```
to creerRenard

  create-Renards 10
  ask Renards
  [
  move-to one-of patches with [ cimetary = 1 ]
  set size 6
  set color red
  ]

  ask renard 1
  [set poids 3
   set stress 25]

    ask renard 2
  [set poids 3.5
   set stress 25]

    ask renard 3
  [set poids 4
   set stress 25]

    ask renard 4
  [set poids 4.5
   set stress 25]

    ask renard 5
  [set poids 5
   set stress 25]

    ask renard 6
  [set poids 5.5
   set stress 25]

    ask renard 7
  [set poids 6
   set stress 25]

    ask renard 8
  [set poids 6.5
   set stress 25]

    ask renard 9
  [set poids 7
   set stress 25]

end
```

Comment: Is your problem that you can't work out how to code the condition that specifies WHEN to create a line of output, or is the problem that you don't know HOW to create a line of output? I can't see how the code you provided bears any relationship to either of these questions, sorry, so more detail is needed. If your problem is about HOW, then use `type`. `show` and `print` to get the correct format reporting to the command centre, then change those commands into `file-type` etc.

Comment: thank you for your answer, my problem is that I don't know how to create a line of output to get both turtles variable (stress and poids) in one file with the turtles in order in the first column and stress and poids in two others next to it

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this is an answer to avoid ongoing discussion in comments, even though I am not entirely clear what you want. Try putting in a line like this:

```
ask turtles
[ if random-float 1 < 0.2
  [ type "I am turtle " type who type ", poids of "
      type poids type ", stress of ", print stress
  ]
]
```

This is not a solution, but it will give you an idea of how to approach what you want to do. You will need to replace the condition with one that involves crossing the boundary.

This code will print to the command center. Adjust the `type` and `print` until you have the format you actually want in the file (csv is usually easiest) and then use `file-type` instead of `type` and `file-print` instead of `print`. You will also need to open and close the file. Look at the NetLogo dictionary file I/O section for an example.